# External database access in Wordpress plugin

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins, mdb2

I have developped a small Wordpress plugin that filter the page content setup thru a add_filter('the_content'...) call.

My filtering function does include PHP files that makes external database calls thru the use of Pear MDB2 classes, it appears that after these database functions have finished executing, all Wordpress calls outside the filtering function that need Wordpress database are failing. The page does not display categories and apparently no dynamic content that uses the Wordpress database.

Is there a call I need to make in my filtering function so Wordpress database access is restored ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should try this to see if you have a (wp)DB connection.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
var_dump($wpdb);
?>
```

$wpdb is the object which connects to the db
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb